# Accessing iPhone missed calls, text messages, push notifications etc

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

I'm wandering if it's possible (and if yes, how) to access information about missed calls, unread text messages, unread push notifications etc. using some API?

From reading around, it seems the formal APIs don't allow for this - any pointers about how to do this on a jail-broken device?

Thanks,

Comment: LockInfo seems to be able to have access to all this data and more, so it definitely ought to be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a sample app that someone made that showed you how to get this data on a non-jail-broken phone. It was called "SpyPhone." It's been a while since that project was released though so I don't know if it still works. And of course, making any calls like this will get your app rejected by the App Store reviewers.

I can't find the sample project anymore but here are slides on a talk he did on the project: http://www.scribd.com/doc/23739469/iPhone-Privacy-from-Nicolas-Seriot

Hope this helps!

Comment: Actually, the presentation itself has a link to the project: http://github.com/nst/spyphone